# Getting/setting MailItem permissions (classification) in Outlook 2010/2013 from VSTO addin

Tags: permissions, outlook, vsto, classification

I figured out how one can add custom classifications to Outlook (using a locally deployed classification.xml and related policy registry key). These custom values show up in the Permission split button menu and using the UI I can set the classification. However what I need to do is some custom action depending on the actively selected classification value. And here's my challenge. whatever is set in the UI doesn't seem to be reflected in the Permissions or PermissionTemplateGuid properties.
Can anybody tell me how to get the active classification for a MailItem (more specifically the one currently being composed)

EDIT: since the old working code addressed the problem by checking commandbar button status, which clearly will no longer work in Outlook 2013 - I'm also willing to accept an answer if you tell me how to make a ribbon based equivalent - as it's not possible to repurpose the built in PermissionRestrictMenu split button.

```
Office.CommandBarPopup permissionControl = mailItem.GetInspector.CommandBars.FindControl(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, AddinConfigurationManager.PermissionControlId, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
                    as Office.CommandBarPopup;
Office.CommandBarButton restrictedDistributionButton = GetRestrictedDistributionControlIndex(permissionControl);
```

where GetRestrictedDistributionControlIndex deals with permissionControl.get_accChild

Comment: Do you see the change after you save the item? How about after restarting Outlook?

Comment: What code do you use for getting property values? Be aware, Outlook doesn't propagate changes to/from the Outlook object model. You need to save items to get changes visible to others.

Comment: Any changes made in the UI are persisted - but only reflected in the UI. Saving/restarting did not help to access classification from code. So the whole story is that I need to fix an add-in (that was contractually built by 3rd party some years ago for my company) which works on Outlook2010 but not 2013 as the code deals with CommandBars that were deprecated. (see edited post for code snippet)

Comment: Eugene, i'm only using MailItem object's property Permission and PermissionTemplateGuid respectively but not PropertyAccessor. Is there some Mapi property that i could use?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out eventually. I found some named MAPI properties under the PSETID_Common property-set that do the trick, namely Classified, Classification, ClassificationDescription, ClassificationGuid and ClassificationKeep.
For detecting a classification set from the UI I'm only getting the value of Classification named proptag. I found this tag to be accessible using the below id namespace:

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/85B6001F"
```

For setting classification of a MailItem I've had success with setting the properties in this specific order: Classification, ClassificationDescription, ClassificationGuid, Classified and ClassificationKeep.

```
string PSETID_Common = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/"
Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = mailItem.PropertyAccessor;
pa.SetProperty(PSETID_Common + "85B6001F", "short name");  // set short name
pa.SetProperty(PSETID_Common + "85B7001F", "description");  // set description
pa.SetProperty(PSETID_Common + "85B8001F", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");  // set GUID
pa.SetProperty(PSETID_Common + "85B5000B", true); // Mark as Classified
pa.SetProperty(PSETID_Common + "85BA000B", true); // Keep classification
```